# Different images for ViewPager depending on Android's screen aspect ratio

Tags: android, screen, aspect-ratio

I want to display images occupying the entire width and height of Android devices for ViewPager and to accomplish that I have both 4x3 and 16x9 images.

Is there a way to programmatically change the set of images so it fits (almost full-screen) Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your images in the appropriate res/drawable folder.

E.g. you can put your 16/9 images in `drawable-long`, and 4/3 images in `drawable-notlong`.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)